# Erro: object of type 'float' has no len

Tags: python, string, variáveis, memória, float

Eu estava *debugando* operações simples no interpretador do Python, e o comando a seguir me tornou esta curiosidade:

```
>>> b = 3.12; len(b)
```

Com o seguinte erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

No meu entendimento o interpretador Python está acusando que o objeto do tipo `float` não tem tamanho. Não sei, eu estava esperando que a saída fosse 3 ou 4 que seria a quantidade de dígitos que ele demonstra, contando o ponto ou não.

Answer (score 6):

Ele até tem um tamanho na memória, mas a função `len()` não é para analisar o tamanho ocupado na memória. E nem é a intenção, afinal sua expectativa é que ele mostrasse a quantidade de dígitos que é mostrado no número. São coisas completamente diferentes. A forma como o dado está na memória e como ele é mostrado na tela - ou é armazenado em algum lugar para um humano ver - são coisas bem diferentes.

Você está vendo uma representação do dado em forma de caracteres gráficos que por acaso são dígitos numéricos. Mas o importante aí é que são caracteres. O que você está vendo é uma sequência (cadeia) de caracteres, ou seja, está vendo uma *string*. Então para saber o tamanho dessa *string*, você tem que dizer que quer isto. Tem que transformar o número no tipo `string` e aí dá para usar a função `len()` para saber quantos caracteres ela tem.

A função `len()` está disponível para alguns tipos de dados, não para todos. O dado numérico em si tem um tamanho na memória que é um detalhe de implementação. A gente sabe que é 4 bytes, mas isto não importa na maior parte do tempo. *Len* é a contração de *length*, ou seja, comprimento. Então ela não fornece exatamente o tamanho de nada, mas sim o comprimento. Há uma diferença sutil aí. O comprimento pode ser obtido em todo tipo que seja uma sequência de alguma coisa. Que é o caso de uma *string*.

A forma mais simples de converter `float` para `string` é com a função [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#func-str):

```
b = 3.12; len(str(b))
```

Outra forma é com o [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#repr):

```
b = 3.12; len(repr(b))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qCmQSn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ygwelhoo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/LenFloat.py).

Comment: realmente @bigown na documentação do python não especifica o tipo float na função len() mas voce saberia como eu posso então recuperar a quantidade caracteres de uma variavel do tipo float, outra pergunta variaveis do tipo int e do tipo float e outras do tipo numerico ocupam o mesmo espaço na memoria é isso 4 bytes

Comment: Da forma como eu te mostrei acima. Coloquei um exemplo funcionando agora para ver. Em Python tanto o `int`, quanto o `float` ocupam 4 bytes, mas não sei se isto é uma garantia da linguagem (acredito que sim), tem linguagens que garantem isto, outras deixam em aberto e não pode confiar nisto.

Comment: A função "len" não mostra a "quantidade de digitos" de um número nem a quantidade de caracteres de uma string  - ela devolve o comprimento de uma sequência. O tamanho em Bytes na memoria de um objeto Python não tem nada a ver com  ele implementar ou não o protocolo de sequência (e portanto ter ou não `len')

Comment: E foi justamente o que eu falei. Quando você não entende a resposta, você pede esclarecimento, não negativa.

Comment: Eu entendi a resposta - o negativo é por conta do "me parece que nem é a intenção". Não é a intenção _mesmo_. E não tem nada a ver com a quantidade de dígitos - tem a ver com o objeto ser uma sequência ou não: são conceitos errados o suficiente para eu negativar a resposta - uam vez que são misleading.

Comment: Mas eu achei que o OP queria saber o tamanho do float na memoria, de fato, nem me passou pela cabeça que ele possa estar querendo, de fato, o comprimento da representação decimal do dado - nesse sentido, de fato,a  resposta não precisa ser negativada. Mas o S.O. me bloqueia mudar o voto a não ser que a resposta seja editada.

Comment: O comentário dele deixa claro que é isso mesmo que ele quer.

Comment: ok. eu assumi que ele queria o tamanho na mamória de um float, justamente por que li o começo da sua resposta. Para eu tirar o voto negativo, ela precisa ser editada - você poderia mudar só o "Me parece que nem é essa aintenção" para "Nem é essa a intenção"?

Comment: Pronto, deixei mais claro.

Comment: a minha pergunta ficou meio que sem pé e nem cacbeça já que o o resultado que eu estava esperando obter era o comprimento da minha variavel float e não tinha nada há ver com a memoria

Comment: @SandroG a gente compreende, quando se está aprendendo os conceitos ficam confusos, mas tenho tenho certeza que agora entende melhor do assunto.

Answer (score 5):

Ao contrário de C, o tamanho que objetos Python ocupam na memória é abstraído, e a principio um programa Python não precisa saber do mesmo.

Claro que é bom ter uma noção -  e eventualemente você pode otimizar alguma coisa, por exemplo, usando namedtuples em vez de dicionários, etc.... A função `len` é praticamente um operador em Python: ela devolve a quantidade de itens de uma sequência -  e isso não tem nada a ver com o tamanho do objeto sequência na memória, nem com os objetos dentro da sequência.

Um número inteiro, ou float, ou outro tipo não é uma sequência. Uma string de texto é uma sequência, mas o valor retornado por `len` para a mesma pode não ter relação alguma com o seu tamanho na memória: se for um objeto de texto unicode, cada caractér pode ocupar 4 bytes. Se for um texto codificado em utf-8, os caractéres tem comprimento variável em bytes, e assim por diante.

Dito isso, Python tem uma função auxiliar para dizer o tamanho em bytes de um objeto na memória - no módulo `sys`, a função `getsizeof`.

Então você conseguira o que estava tentando fazendo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> b = 3.12
>>> sys.getsizeof(b)
24
```

E a resposta é essa: 24 - um objeto Python do tipo "float" ocupa 24 bytes na memória. O dado em si, o número, no caso específico do float em Python é um float IEEE 754 de 64bits - que usa 8 bytes - os demais 16 bytes do objeto float são metadados usados pelo Python para controlar o ciclo de vida do objeto, dentre outras coisas.

Como eu disse antes, essa informação não é muito útil. Ou o seu programa vai ter algumas poucas variáveis de ponto flutuante - menos que 10 ou 20, e fazer alguma conta com elas, e nesse caso esse tamanho em bytes numa máquina com várias centenas de megabytes de memória, como é tipicamente a memória de máquinas que rodam Python, é irrelevante, ou, se você estiver trabalhando com computação científica, em que o tamanho em memória de um número pode fazer diferença, você vai estar usando objetos especializados para armazenar 
seus números (mesmo por que é essencial que as operações matemáticas  e lógicas em cima de dados em massa seja feita em código nativo). Normalmente se usam as arrays da biblioteca numpy em código desse tipo - mas você também pode usar as arrays nativas da stdlib do Python. Qualquer uma das duas permite que você especifique o tipo exato de dado de cada elemento, e aí você pode escolher usar floats de 32 ou 64bits (4 ou 8 bytes por número). No caso do numpy há inclusive suporte a floats de 128bit (16 bytes, mas isso pode ficar lento, uma vez que não há suporte em hardware nas CPUs atuais para esse tipo de dado).

Comment: agora conseguiu dar uma clareada, preciso conhecer mais as funçoes do python e obrigado pela ajuda vlw!